# List iterator as an unordered-map key

Tags: c++, list, iterator, key, unordered-map

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main ()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::list<int>::iterator, int> map;

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. Error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<std::_List_iterator<int> >) (const std::_List_iterator<int>&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

I assume that I can't use list iterator as a map key for some reason, but is there any way to make it work? I can change my design not to require that but I'd prefer to have list iterator as a map key.

Comment: List iterators don't have a hash function defined (as you can see from the error message). So you should provide your own custom hash function. I guess that would work, although is it a bit odd.

Comment: If you want to resolve the error, you need to specialise the `std::hash` class for your key type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define how the hash is generated for `std::List<int>::iterator`. You can do this by specialising the `std::hash` template struct for this type. Here is a naive implementation:

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<std::list<int>::iterator>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(std::list<int>::iterator const& iter) const noexcept
        {
            return  (std::size_t)&(*iter);
        }
    };
}
```

The one upside is that it avoids collisions.

Also, this is one of the few instances where you are permitted to define a struct inside the `std` namespace.